# Связать MySQL и PHP

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Я новичок. Мне нужно сверстать очень простой сайт с новостями, которые находятся в базе данных mysql (есть этот файл), Я сверстал основу, как связать с базой, чтобы оттуда построчно выходили новости при помощи php?

```
$page = 0;
$news_per_page_limit = 5;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 5';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT " . $page . ", " . $news_per_page_limit;


$current_page = $page * $news_per_page_limit;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT " . $current_page . ", " . $news_per_page_limit;
```

Думаю, что нужно делать как-то так, но точно не знаю.
Можно ли сделать это всё без phpmyadmin или чего-то подобного, просто имея файл?

Comment: про какой файл вы говорите?

Comment: у меня есть файл формата sql, открытый в vs code,  в нём находится данный код и далее записи таблицы с новостями
```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `news`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `announce` text,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_news_idate` (`idate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Файл SQL может содержать утверждения, которые создают или изменяют операции с базами данных или другим файлом SQL (например, операции обновления, удаления и т.д.). Для того, чтобы правильно прочитать и выполнить файл SQL, он должен быть открыт в программе базы данных, которая поддерживает язык Structure Query Language. Использовать такой файл в качестве источника данных не получится.

Comment: А не посоветуете, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь такие программы для mac os простые в установке, ибо phpmyadmin  очень непонятен, большое спасибо

Comment: phpmyadmin это не база данных, это инструмент для подключения к базе данных, вам нужно установить непосредственно MySQL и научиться подключаться к нему из PHP, обращаться к нему с SQL запросом который вы сформировали (SELECT *...) и получать от него ответ который уже использовать для вывода данных на сайте, если у вас совсем простенький сайт поищите про `mysqli` в гугле

Comment: большое спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
$database = 'name_db'; // имя базы данных
$user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]